# Pydub and Aplay: suppress verbose output?

Tags: python-2.7, audio, pydub

I'm trying to suppress the output of aplay, but without success.
I know how to suppress print statments with stdout, but I didn't figured out how to archive the same result with pydub module. 
For example when I play a sound with this code

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

next_kot = AudioSegment.from_ogg('/home/effe/Voz/Hello.ogg')
play(next_kot)
```

The output generated (in red!) is

> avplay version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2014
>   the Libav developers   built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8
>   (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) Input #0, wav, from '/tmp/tmp5DUj0a.wav':
>   Duration: 00:00:01.32, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
>       Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s

When you concatenate more audio is easy to lose key information.
Is there a way to cut off this kind of output?

Thanks.

Comment: @Jiaaro: any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue and here is what I did. You can just create a new function named _play_with_ffplay_suppress and have the following code in it. The difference between the answer above and mine is that Jiaaro used

```
stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w')
stderr=os.stdout
```

and I used "devnull" after creating a variable with the same name.  Very tiny difference but I hope it solves the error that you mentioned in the comment.

```
stderr=devnull
stdout=devnull
```

Here is my code:

```
#rhp - additional import added
import os

#rhp-custom function to supress output while playing mp3 files
def _play_with_ffplay_suppress(seg):
    with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
        seg.export(f.name, "wav")
        devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        subprocess.call([PLAYER,"-nodisp", "-autoexit", "-hide_banner", f.name],stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

For more information you can read about the call function in the subprocess module in Python here https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html.

Comment: Simple and effective. I don't know why I didn't think on it.

Answer (score 1):

the playback functions are really simple (and mostly included for easy use in the interactive python shell) - Your best bet is probably to make a copy of the [playback code](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/playback.py) that is better suited to your needs:

if you're using ffplay this should work:

```
import os
from pydub.utils import get_player_name

PLAYER = get_player_name()

def play_with_ffplay(seg):
    with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
        seg.export(f.name, "wav")
        subprocess.call(
            [PLAYER, "-nodisp", "-autoexit", f.name],
            stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'), 
            stderr=os.stdout
        )
```

note: ffmpeg is always going to open a new window for ffplay though - I'd recommend installing pyaudio and using that for playback instead

Comment: stderr=os.stdout
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stdout'